# Complex multidimensional loop into a table

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a problem populating a table from a complex loop.

The table is composed of 7 days calendar table and each day should contain the day events under it.

```
Array
(
    [2012-12-16] => Array
        (
        )

    [2012-12-17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2012-12-17
                    [time_booked] => 00:09:00
                    [time_start] => 00:00:00
                    [time_end] => 00:00:00
                    [name] => maha mostafa elrashed
                    [first_name] => marwan
                    [title] => root cannal
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2012-12-17
                    [time_booked] => 09:00:00
                    [time_start] => 00:00:00
                    [time_end] => 00:00:00
                    [name] => demo demo eldemo
                    [first_name] => marwan
                    [title] => ultrasound
                )

        )

    [2012-12-18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2012-12-18
                    [time_booked] => 09:00:00
                    [time_start] => 00:00:00
                    [time_end] => 00:00:00
                    [name] => demo demo eldemo
                    [first_name] => marwan
                    [title] => root cannal
                )

        )

    [2012-12-19] => Array
        (
        )

    [2012-12-20] => Array
        (
        )

    [2012-12-21] => Array
        (
        )

    [2012-12-22] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

This example of array I want to convert into a table. currently I find the easiest way is to print each **day as ul and float left them**, but what I really want is to make a table out of them to be able to sort that table using jQuery in future.

```
foreach($ztable as $t){
    echo"\n<ul style='float:left;width:140px'>";
    foreach($t as $r){
        echo "<li class='{$r['first_name']}'>{$r['name']}</li>";
    }
        echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

Any suggestions?
I'm using Codeigniter 2 by the way

Edit:

[image: top table is from the suggested answer, the lower one is how I want it to be]

Top table is from the suggested answer, the lower one is how I want it to be.

Comment: take a look at CI auto table generation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague. You are saying you want to build a `<ul>`, while having working code, while you actually want to build a table. Hmm.

Here's how you can do a table:

```
// list of fields that will be rows
$fields = array(
    'date' => 'Date', 
    'time_booked' => 'Time of booking', 
    'time_start' => 'Start time',
    'time_end' => 'End time',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'first_name' => 'First name',
    'title' => 'Title'
    );

// echo table header
echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>Day</th>';
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    echo '<th>' . $field . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// echo table rows
foreach($ztable as $day => $data)
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $day . '</td>';
    // if some field is not present for current day, we show '-'
    foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field)
    {
        echo '<td>' . (isset($data[$field_name]) ? $data[$field_name] : '-') . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I don't think this will work fully; need to loop through `$data` as it will be an array. `         if(! empty($data)){
          foreach($data as $k => $v){
           echo $v[$field_name]."<br>";
          }
         }else{
          echo "-";
         }`

Comment: @stormdrain Judging by the array was provided, he might not have data for some days and I assume for some there will be non-complete data sets. That's why looping through `$data` may ruin table layout, while looping through pre-defined set of fields will always produce same layout, with data or with '-' where there's no data.

Comment: In the loop I commented with, it checks to see if the array is empty first and if it is places a "-" in there: `if(! empty($data))`

Comment: well yp i want it in a table, but i want the Date to be On <th> so that one day can contain more than 1 row (row  will show only [first_name]

Answer (score 1):

Since you added a picture with what you want, I threw together some gross-looking code that gets results:

```
//provided $a is the array
//table header with dates
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<tr>";

foreach($a as $date => $data){
    echo "<th>$date</th>";
}

echo "</tr>";

//table row for appointment dates
echo "<tr>";

foreach($a as $k=>$v){

    //if the array value isn't empty, we have data
    if(! empty($v)){

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<ul>";

        //loop through the array to get all the names
        foreach($v as $k => $v){

            echo "<li>".$v['name']."</li>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</td>";

    }else{
            //there was no data for the date; empty td
        echo "<td></td>";

    }

}

echo "</tr></table>";
```

Should be enough to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I think your array is not formatted correctly. Please try this format.

```
Array('2012-12-16' => Array(),
            '2012-12-17' => Array
                (
                '0' => Array
                    (
                    'date' => '2012-12-17',
                    'time_booked' => '00:09:00',
                    'time_start' => '00:00:00',
                    'time_end' => '00:00:00',
                    'name' => 'maha mostafa elrashed',
                    'first_name' => 'marwan',
                    'title' => 'root cannal'
                ),
                '1' => Array
                    (
                    'date' => '2012-12-17',
                    'time_booked' => '09:00:00',
                    'time_start' => '00:00:00',
                    'time_end' => '00:00:00',
                    'name' => 'demo demo eldemo',
                    'first_name' => 'marwan',
                    'title' => 'ultrasound'
                )
            ),
            '2012-12-18' => Array
                (
                '0' => Array
                    (
                    'date' => '2012-12-18',
                    'time_booked' => '09:00:00',
                    'time_start' => '00:00:00',
                    'time_end' => '00:00:00',
                    'name' => 'demo demo eldemo',
                    'first_name' => 'marwan',
                    'title' => 'root cannal'
                )
            ),
            '2012 - 12 - 19' => Array
            (
            ),
            '2012 - 12 - 20' => Array
            (
            ),
            '2012 - 12 - 21' => Array
            (
            ),
            '2012 - 12 - 22' => Array
            (
            )
        );
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you are seeing there in the OP is a dump of the array, not how it is set.

Comment: @stormdrain yp its a dump of the array